# How can I show many lists on one plot?

Tags: plotting

Can anyone help me to show many lists on one plot. I have the following data;

```
Outputakhir = 
  TableForm[Transpose[{tlist, k1list, k2list, eb1list, eb2list, n1list, n2list}]]
```

> ```
> TableForm[
>     {{masa, kest1, kest2, entrop1, entrop2, negat1, negat2}, 
>      {0, 1, 1, -13.999999999999998, -13.999999999999998, 0, 0}, 
>      {12.004999999999981, 1., 0.9999691595472917, -13.999961890377083, 
>       -13.99986434867277, -0.00001542093979234327, -0.000023131052976799182}, 
>      {24.05699999999996, 1., 0.9960264734652062, -13.994434468268233, 
>       -13.981842876500487, -0.001998796793604707, -0.002992194397865189}, 
>      {36.12499999999994, 1., 0.9815234829836469, -13.961735659671618, 
>       -13.90272335915691, -0.009515058436080692, -0.014135909155472803}, 
>      {48.223999999999926, 1., 0.9462186035211008, -13.768212830773868, 
>       -13.5919332913098, -0.029694686123548975, -0.04319194284310213}}]
> ```

I want to plot `{k1list, k2list, eb1list, eb2list, n1list, n2list}}` as a function of `masa`, all in a single cell, but withe each list drawn with a different pattern of line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
raw = {{masa, kest1, kest2, entrop1, entrop2, negat1, negat2}, {0, 1, 
    1, -13.999999999999998, -13.999999999999998, 0, 
    0}, {12.004999999999981, 1., 
    0.9999691595472917, -13.999961890377083, -13.99986434867277,
    -0.00001542093979234327, -0.000023131052976799182},
    {24.05699999999996, 1., 
    0.9960264734652062, -13.994434468268233, -13.981842876500487,
    -0.001998796793604707, -0.002992194397865189}, {36.12499999999994, 1.,
    0.9815234829836469, -13.961735659671618, -13.90272335915691,
    -0.009515058436080692, -0.014135909155472803}, {48.223999999999926, 
    1., 0.9462186035211008, -13.768212830773868, -13.5919332913098,
    -0.029694686123548975, -0.04319194284310213}};

data = raw[[2 ;; 6]];
{row, col} = Dimensions[data];
x = data[[All, 1]];
y = Transpose@Table[data[[i, 2 ;; col]], {i, 1, row}];
tempData = TemporalData[y, {x}];
ListLinePlot[tempData, PlotLegends -> raw[[1]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. I try it first

Comment: I already try it but not get the result. Can @Young explain me what the meaning each of the coding you write. tq

Comment: @munirah Did you see how I removed the `TableForm` command?

Comment: Yes, i know about that. what it mean by 1.raw[[2 ;; 6]],

Comment: @munirah I'm taking the part of the table with the data, removing the heading ... if you are using this on a table with more rows you will need to increase the number 6

Comment: I see. Now, I understand. I will try it back. Thank you very much for helping me

Answer (score 4):

**Description**

Here is an alternative solution. Note, `raw` is your original data.

**Example**

```
ListLinePlot @ (Transpose[{raw[[2 ;; All, 1]], #}] & @ # & /@ Table[raw[[2 ;; All, i]], {i, 2, Length @ raw}])
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Tqvm. Iwill try it